# Error in applying a for loop to an xtable in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable

I'm preparing a pdf using knitr that contains a table produced using xtable. I'm adding a bold typeface to certain cells in the table so I've written the following function:

```
bold <- function(x, matrix){
        x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)
          for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {   
            yes <- matrix[,i]
              x[yes,i] <- paste('\\textbf{', x[yes,i], '}', sep = "")  
          } 
                print(x, sanitize.text.function = identity)
}
```

My intention is that the object 'l.mat' is a logical matrix and by changing the 1's and 0's in the matrix I can change which cells are bold.

The function seems to produce the desired result but when I compile the document the 'include.rownames = FALSE' argument in print.xtable does not seem to work and I'm getting the following error printed in the pdf:

```
TRUE Error in rep(" ", nrow(x) + 2): invalid ’times’ argument
```

Here's how I'm creating the matrix I'm using for the logical test:

```
l.vec <- as.logical(c(1,1,1,1,1,
                      1,1,1,1,1,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,1))

l.mat <- matrix(l.vec, nrow = 6, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
```

And here's how I'm printing the table:

```
x.df.2 <- (xtable(df.2))

x.df.3 <- bold(x.df.2, l.mat)

print.xtable(x.df.3, include.rownames = FALSE)
```

I'm already well out of my depth here and I can't wrap my head around this problem. I feel like I don't understand enough about how xtable, latex and knitr work and interact to understand this error. Any guidance as to what's causing these errors would be very helpful.

Sample data frame:

```
df.2 <-     DATE   CY   FY Quarter  XEMPNIN
        275 2043:3 2043 2044       3 3324.391
        276 2043:4 2043 2044       4 3326.214
        277 2044:1 2044 2044       1 3328.492
        278 2044:2 2044 2044       2 3330.100
        279 2044:3 2044 2045       3 3331.963
        280 2044:4 2044 2045       4 3334.248
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The problem is with your `bold()` function. Try:

```
bold <- function(x, matrix) {

  x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)

  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {   
    yes <- matrix[,i]
    x[yes,i] <- paste('\\textbf{', x[yes,i], '}', sep = "")  
  } 
  return(x)
}
```

and add the `sanitize.text` to the `print.xtable()` call:

```
print.xtable(
  x.df.3, 
  include.rownames = FALSE, 
  sanitize.text.function = identity
  )
```

This should give you what you want:

[image: xtable_output]

A fully reproducible .Rnw file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/ivyleavedtoadflax/70d7d7a04ee3f81982d3).

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I was so close, I had convinced myself there was some complex knitr/latex problem.